# How to create mutual one-to-zero-or-one relationships and navigation properties in EF?

Tags: entity-framework, relationship

I am struggling to get this concept in EF code-first. Essentially it is 2 tables with foreign keys to each other. Both the relations should be one-to-zero-or-one. I.e. both optional.
[image]

This is my attempt:

```
  public class Blog
  {
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int BlogId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("PostId")]
    public virtual Post Post { get; set; }
    public int? PostId { get; set; }
  }

  public class Post
  {
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int PostId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("BlogId")]
    public virtual Blog Blog { get; set; }
    public int? BlogId { get; set; }
  }
```

But this, of course ends up with this error:

> Unable to determine the principal end of an association between the
>   types 'EFTest.Models.Post' and 'EFTest.Models.Blog'. The principal end
>   of this association must be explicitly configured using either the
>   relationship fluent API or data annotation

Ok, so I try with something like this:

```
  modelBuilder.Entity<Blog>()
    .HasOptional(b => b.Post)
    .WithOptionalPrincipal(p => p.Blog);

  modelBuilder.Entity<Post>()
    .HasOptional(b => b.Blog)
    .WithOptionalDependent(p => p.Post);
```

But that doesn't create the desired foreign keys in the DB.
I find the naming concept in the fluent API very confusing, I have tried a multitude of variants and search SO for similar questions, but so far no luck.
I want proper FKs, EF navigation properties. Either of the entities could be the Principal.

Can anyone shed some tips?

Comment: But this not *one-to-one* relationship. *one-to-one* relationships are mapped through their primary keys. If you have foreign key, this is *one-to-many* relationship. More than one `Blog` can have same `PostId`, and vice versa, more than one `Post` can have same `BlogId`.

Comment: Setup the DB the way you like and use the reverse engineer tool to see what EF gives you.

Answer (score 0):

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<Blog>().HasOptional(b => b.Post).WithRequired(p => p.Blog);
```

I've used this in the past. This is saying a Blog can have a null post. But a Post must reference a Blog.